# Inheritable object structure

Tags: inheritance, layout, nim-lang

From my experiments, i see that inheritable objects start with 4 additional bytes (i have a 32 cpu). From this observation, i'd like to know:

- Does it depend on the architecture? (ie. 8 bytes for 64 cpu)
- How are these bytes used? It is one field or several ones?
- I defined an heterogeneous container which copies objects except these four bytes using copyMem (i want contigious seqs without using variants). Should i be concerned about something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way to figure out this kind of question is to look at the intermediate C file. I compiled this file:

```
type Foo = object {.inheritable.}
  x: int

var a: Foo
echo sizeof(a)
```

After compiling it with `nim -d:release c x` a look into `nimcache/x.c` reveals:

```
struct  Foo118004  {
TNimType* m_type;
NI x;
};
```

So there is simply a pointer to a `TNimType` object stored. The size of the pointer and the alignment of the `Foo` object are system and compiler dependent, but it should be 8 bytes for x86_64 and 4 bytes for x86. `TNimType` itself can be found in `lib/system/hti.nim` and is defined like this:

```
TNimType {.codegenType.} = object
  size: int
  kind: TNimKind
  flags: set[TNimTypeFlag]
  base: ptr TNimType
  node: ptr TNimNode # valid for tyRecord, tyObject, tyTuple, tyEnum
  finalizer: pointer # the finalizer for the type
  marker: proc (p: pointer, op: int) {.nimcall, benign.} # marker proc for GC
  deepcopy: proc (p: pointer): pointer {.nimcall, benign.}
```